# Change of Variable - Double Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area, change-of-variable

I have the following question:

Using $u=xy$ and $v=\frac{x}{y}$, solve the integral
$$I = \int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=x}^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{x^3}{y}\exp\left((xy)^2+\frac{x^2}{y^2}\right)\,dy\,dx$$
I find computing the Jacobian and the integral ok, it’s finding the inverse of the $u=xy$ and $v=\frac{x}{y}$ (i.e. rearranging for $x=…$ and $y=…$) that I keep struggling with. Can someone explain the process, as solutions always skip the steps as it’s the ‘easy’ part of the problem.

Comment: You need to solve the system of equations regarding $u,v$ and find images of old restrictions in new variables. What exactly does not work?

Comment: That is the long way. You can also find the inverse Jacobian with the equations as written, i.e. with $u=\cdots$ and $v=\cdots$. The inverse Jacobian is simply the reciprocal of the Jacobian.

Comment: I added a bracket, for one you hadn't partnered, in what I _think_ is the right place. Review my edit in case I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverting the equations is not necessary. Instead using the $u$ and $v$ equations one can solve for the inverse Jacobian

$$J^{-1} = \left|\begin{vmatrix}y&x\\\frac{1}{y}&-\frac{x}{y^2}\end{vmatrix}\right| = \left|-\frac{x}{y}-\frac{x}{y}\right| = \frac{2x}{y}$$

then the Jacobian is simply

$$J = \frac{1}{J^{-1}} = \frac{1}{\frac{2x}{y}} = \frac{1}{2v}$$

Comment: Thanks, we hadn’t been shown this. To confirm, the region becomes the square bounded by the points: $(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)$, giving integral $\int_0^1\int_0^1uv^2exp(u^2+v^2)\frac{1}{2v}dvdu = \frac{exp(2)-2exp(1)+exp(0)}{8} \approx 0.369$